# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$where(city_id,1)

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make conditions on my search query, when I use this code I got this error :
my code :

```
$condition = null;
foreach (session()->get('filters') as $items)`
{
    $condition .= "where(".$items['type'].",".$items['value'].")->";
}
$cars = Car::where('is_active','active')->$condition->get();
```

My error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$where(city_id,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add methods to an existing query, start your query with `$query = Car::newQuery()`. Then just append your methods to that variable.

```
$query = Car::newQuery();
$query = $query->where('is_active', 'active');

foreach (session()->get('filters') as $items) {
    $query = $query->where($items['type'], $items['value']);
}

$cars = $query->get();
```